# Отбросить нули слева

Tags: java

Предполагается что этот метод будет отбрасывть нули слева от числа,

на вход получили 000101
на выходе 101

Что происходит на деле:
на вход 000101
на выходе 65
WTF??
Еще пара примеров входа/выхода

0001024  532

0002020  1040

00020101  8257

```
public String divideWithFix(Integer dividend, Integer divisor) {
        String dividendStr = dividend.toString();
        {
            StringBuilder sbDividend = new StringBuilder(dividendStr);
            char cha = '0';
            for (int i = 0; i<dividendStr.length(); i++) {
                if (dividendStr.charAt(i) == cha) {
                    sbDividend.deleteCharAt(i);
                    System.out.println(dividendStr); //TODO
                    System.out.println(sbDividend.toString()); //TODO
                }
                dividendStr = sbDividend.toString();
                break;
            }
        }
        String divisorStr = divisor.toString();
        {
            StringBuilder sbDivisor = new StringBuilder(divisorStr);
            char cha = '0';
            for (int i = 1; i<divisorStr.length(); i++) {
                if (divisorStr.charAt(i) == cha) {
                    sbDivisor.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
                divisorStr = sbDivisor.toString();
                break;
            }
        }
        int fixedDividend = Integer.parseInt(dividendStr);
        int fixedDivisor = Integer.parseInt(divisorStr);
        System.out.println(fixedDividend); //TODO
        System.out.println(fixedDivisor); //TODO
        String result = makeDivision(fixedDividend, fixedDivisor);
        return result;
    }
```

**Как выяснилось, проблема заключается в переводе из строчного типа в целочисленый, перевод происходит в 8 системе исчисления. Как исправить эту проблему?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2800839/7485582

Comment: По опыту скажу, что использование Stringbuilder будет сильно грузить процессор

Comment: *на вход 000101 на выходе 65 WTF??* Числовой литерал, начинающийся нулём, трактуется как число в восьмеричной системе счисления.

Comment: @Arty Morris а порождать кучу стрингов лучше, чем Stringbuilder?

Comment: @nikoshi, я не говорил как надо делать по-другому. Я предупредил об особенностях StringBuilder

Comment: @Arty Morris   а что лучше использовать?

Comment: @nikoshi, смотря какая задача. Что касается этой, я не вникал

Comment: @Arty Morris задача обозначена - отбросить нули из стоки, что тут вникать

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getWithOutZero(String target){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < target.length(); i ++){
        if(target.charAt(i)!='0'){
            result = target.substring(i,target.length());
            return result;
            // Если нужно удалить пробелы
            // return new String(result.replace(" ",""));
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```